# Unable to receive UDP packets in Go app on macOS

Tags: macos, go, network-programming, udp

I am currently facing an issue with my Go application on macOS where I am unable to receive UDP packets. I have implemented a basic UDP listener using the net package, but despite the application reporting that it is listening on the specified UDP port, it does not receive any packets when sending them to my IP address.

Here is part of the code (without error checking):

```
addr, err := net.ResolveUDPAddr("udp", ":1234")
conn, err := net.ListenUDP("udp", addr)
defer conn.Close()

buffer := make([]byte, 1024)
n, _, err := conn.ReadFromUDP(buffer)
fmt.Println("Packet Received!") //never reaches this line
```

I already did this:

- Verified that the firewall on my macOS machine is turned off.
- Tested receiving UDP packets using the nc command-line tool, which was successful when sending packets to localhost (127.0.0.1) from the same machine where the Go application is running.
- However, when I used nc to connect to the computer's own IP address from the same machine, the Go application did not receive any packets.
- Additionally, I tried implementing a Python UDP listener on the same machine, and it successfully received UDP packets when sent to my IP address.
- I also tested it on other computers and it worked fine.

Right now I just need it to show the text.
I think it should receive the udp packet, and print the text after.

Comment: What does the host show as the listening address when you run this? The go listener is correct, so this sounds more like a host configuration issue.

Comment: I don't know if I understand the question, but I think this is it:
fmt.Println(addr.String()) prints :1234 and
fmt.Println(conn.LocalAddr()) prints [::]:1234.

If i change the network to udp4 it prints this:
fmt.Println(addr.String()) prints :1234 and
fmt.Println(conn.LocalAddr()) prints 0.0.0.0:1234.
Either way the behavior is the same.

When attempting to start the application for the second time, I encountered the following error message: 'listen udp4 :1234: bind: address already in use. Not sure if it as anything to do with the error.

Comment: It works fine on my computer to both 127.0.0.1 and to the IP# of the outbound network interface. It's likely some issue with firewalls on your machine, which depends on your OS, your configuration, etc. I don't think that this is a Go programming issue. (I see you tagged with macos - my machine is an Intel Mac running Big Sur 11.7.7)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was related to Podman. Upon uninstalling it,the application started receiving UDP packets successfully.
It's worth noting that I'm unsure if the same problem occurs with Docker or other containerization tools. However, in my specific case, removing Podman resolved the issue.